# Is there a CherryPy equivalent to Django Model.objects.filter()?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I know that in Django I can fetch objects from the DB with something like ModelName.objects.filter().

Is there an analogous pattern in CherryPy?

Answer (score 3):

Yes but not native.  There are a couple of python ORM's that appear to work great with cherry pie with similar syntax to django.  SQLAlchemy is an extremely popular very well supported ORM. It has a huge active community and is probably the de-facto python ORM.  THere is a [tool](http://code.google.com/p/webpyte/source/browse/trunk/webpyte/sqlalchemy_tool.py) posted on cherrypy [site](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/SqlAlchemy) that helps with integration.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CherryPy):

Object-relational mappers:

1. SQLAlchemy — a database backend and ORM for Python applications. TurboGears 2.x uses CherryPy as server and SQLAlchemy as its default ORM.[13]
2. SQLObject — a popular ORM for providing an object interface to your database. Supports a number of common database backends: included in the distribution are MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Sybase SQL Server, MaxDB, Microsoft SQL Server and Firebird. TurboGears 1.x uses CherryPy as server and SQLObject as ORM.[14]
3. Storm — the ORM from Canonical Ltd. (makers of Ubuntu)
4. Dejavu[15] — a public domain, thread-safe ORM for Python applications